# Excel formula to list unique value excluding multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following values in a2:14:

```
Red 
Blue
Red
Red
Yellow
(Blank)
Green
Black
Brown
Brown
Green
55
Silver
```

I want to generate a list if unique items in column c, so I have this formula in c2

```
= unique(filter(a2:a14,a2:a14<>""))
```

This removes the blank row, but now I want to remove the row with 55. Bot sure how to add that criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need a slight tweak to the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A14,(A2:A14<>"")*(ISTEXT(A2:A14))))
```

This will also filter text-only values. As long as you don't care about something like 55-blue-1 and exclude it, then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A14,(A2:A14<>"")*(A2:A14<>55)))
```

The '*' acts `AND`, allowing to have multiple criteria.